# PHP Day iterator

Tags: php, date

I'm able to show days from current date to next 3 months with this code:

```
$begin = new DateTime();
$end = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+3 months', strtotime(date("d-m-Y")))));
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$days = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

foreach ( $days as $day ) {
    ...
}
```

I feel the code can be shortened especially for `$end`. Could you help?

Oh, I also want to get previous 3 months. I changed `'+3 months'` to `'-3 months'`but no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, you can directly write

```
$end = new DateTime('+3 months');
```

To go back 3 months, use`3 months ago` instead of `-3 months`.

Comment: Turns out my code was wrong to show previous, -3 months should work as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
$begin    = new DateTime();
$end      = new DateTime('+ 3 months');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$days     = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);
foreach ( $days as $day ) {
    var_dump($day);
}

$begin    = new DateTime('- 3 months'); // '3 months ago' should also work
$end      = new DateTime();
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$days     = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);
foreach ( $days as $day ) {
    var_dump($day);
}
```

Comment: Stefan, how if i want to get 3 months ago from certain date (not current)?

Comment: `$begin = new DateTime('2010-01-01 12:00:00');` and `$begin->modify('-3 months');`

Comment: `$begin = new DateTime('2010-01-01 12:00:00 - 3 months');` will also work (at least on PHP 5.3.3)