# How to loop from today to one year later (one year date range) in PHP

Tags: php, loops

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [PHP Day iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283563/php-day-iterator)
>   [I have 2 dates in PHP, how can I run a foreach loop to go through all of those days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207749/i-have-2-dates-in-php-how-can-i-run-a-foreach-loop-to-go-through-all-of-those-da)

I want to create a loop which creates records for each day from today to one year later.

There is no input for dates.
From date which the form is submitted to the day 1 year after.

How can i do that ?

For example today when i submit the form today, i need a loop from 17/01/2011 to 17/01/2012

Comment: duplicate of [Loop through all months in a date range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155110/php-loop-thru-all-months-in-date-range/2155168#2155168) - same approach

Comment: duplicate of [I have 2 dates in PHP, how can I run a foreach loop to go through all of those days?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207749/i-have-2-dates-in-php-how-can-i-run-a-foreach-loop-to-go-through-all-of-those-da/3207849)

Comment: duplicate of [how to find the dates between two dates specified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736784/how-to-find-the-dates-between-two-dates-specified)

Comment: @Gordon I get the feeling that I've seen this question before, don't you? :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
$next_year = strtotime('+1 year');
$current_time = time();

while($current_time < $next_year){
    $current_time = strtotime('+1 day', $current_time);
    print date('d-m-Y', $current_time);
}
```

You can then use the `$current_time` variable with `date()` to format the time in whatever way you wish.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 year'));
```

Comment: this only returns the next year's date . OP is looking for all days in that period